# I have written a javascript program to create a webpage which calculates the discount is as follows:

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create a web page which calculates the discount for the product for the specific season. The seasons with their discount rates are summer (10%), new year (5%) and clearance (15%). The discount is calculated on the price of the product.

Requirements for the web page are:

The web page background color should be #99FFFF. The label “Discount Price” should be a heading tag(h1) and should be italic bolded, centered, and in color code #b03060.

Product name - a text box with the name "name", should not be empty, contain only alphabets and space and mandatory field.

Price - a number box with the name price, mandatory field and the minimum value should be greater than 15000.

Season is a drop down box with tag name “season”. The drop down box will have the following value and display value

· summer - SUMMER SALE

· newyear - NEW YEAR SALE

· clearance - CLEARANCE SALE

The table should be left aligned with 35% and an outer border style of solid 5px and 30% border width. The space between element and the border must be 10px.

A submit button with left aligned with 45% and with a value “GET DISCOUNT PRICE” should be present. Once submit, the web page calculates the discounted price for the product.

The outcome must be displayed in 2 div tags, where the first will have the id named “discount” and is to display the discount % of the product and the second will have the id named “result” and is to display the discounted price of the product. Both the div tags should be center aligned with bold text. The font of the discounted price must be italic, #FF0000 and 40px size and for discount % it is 25px. Have separate styles for div, discount and result.

I am getting the error :

### Fail 1 - Table tag should have 3 rows and check with the requirements for CSS for table and tr

My code is as follows, can anybody help me to solve this error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color:#99FFFF;
            }
            h1{
                font-style:italic;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#b03060;
            }
            table{
                border-collapse:collapse;
                border:5px solid black;
                width:30%;
                margin-left:35%;
            }
            tr{
                text-align:left;
            }
            td{
                padding:10px;
                border:2px solid black;
            }

            div{
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #result{
                font-style:italic;
                color:#FF0000;
                font-size:40px;
            }
            #discount{
                font-size:25px;
            }
            #submitbutton{
                margin-left:45%;

            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateForm(){
                var season=document.getElementById("s").value;
                var price=parseInt(document.getElementById("price").value);
                var disc;
                if(season=="summer"){
                    disc=10;
                }
                else if(season=="newyear"){
                    disc=5;
                }
                else{
                    disc=15;
                }
                var tot=(price*(100-disc))/100;
                document.getElementById("discount").innerHTML="The discount is "+disc+"%";
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="The discounted price : Rs "+tot;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>DISCOUNT PRICE</h1>
            <form method="get" name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Product Price</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" name="price" required min="15001" id="price">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Season</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="season" id="s">
                                <option value="summer">SUMMER SALE</option>
                                <option value="newyear">NEW YEAR SALE</option>
                                <option value="clearance">CLEARANCE SALE</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbutton" value="GET DISCOUNT PRICE">
                </form><br>
                <div id="discount"></div><br>
                <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your title to summarize your question

Comment: Please reference [mcve] and take special note of the **minimal** request.  There is a lot of information here that seems unnecessary towards demonstrating the issue.  Further more, looking at the code, it is unclear how your browser would give you an error of "Fail 1 - Table tag should have 3 rows and check with the requirements for CSS for table and tr".  That's not a typicaly browser error message